# Creating a cross-platform custom virtual printer in Qt or any other IDE

Tags: qt, cross-platform, virtual-printer

I've searched a lot on this topic but I keep getting more and more confused.

I want to create a cross-platform application (using Qt with C++, for example) that once installed on either MAC or WIN, it will present itself to the system as a virtual printer. So if you hit Ctrl-P on any document, my printer will also be present in the printers list.

My printer will call custom code to extract the data received, create a PDF file, and upload it to some server via FTP.

I looked at "Printing with Qt" documentation here http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/printing.html and also some existing threads suggesting I need to write a Print Driver for MAC(using CUPS) and another one for WIN (using WDK).

I'm just afraid to start in the wrong direction and just waist lots of time ... so anything that points me to the right direction is useful.

Any ideas are welcome !

Thanks

Comment: You've got the right directions (drivers for each OS).

Comment: any idea how easy is it compared to modifying some open source code already available ?

Comment: It's about this difficult: `<---------------->`. (Your question is unanswerable, I have no idea who you are, what your skillset is, or what open source code you're talking about. Obviously starting from scratch is much more complex than adapting something that already exists.)